# Wait on a forked process from a script

Tags: ubuntu, bash, wine

I often run a game (under wine) which requires a CD. I have made an ISO image of the CD, and have written a script to mount it and then launch the game.

I would like to unmount the image once I have exited the game. Unfortunately, wine forks a child process to launch the game, and does not wait for it to die before exiting itself. As a result, the unmount section of my script is executed before the game launches.

What can I add to my script that will wait for the wine child process(es) to end?

I am running Ubuntu 10.04, wine-1.3.26.

Comment: There is a bash command 'wait' that delays until all child processes are dead... did you try that?

Comment: I could wait() on the wine process that **I** launch, but this won't wait for the game (forked by wine, not my script) to terminate before returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there is a wineserver option for this problem exactly. From the wineserver man page:

```
wineserver(1)
    Options
        ...
    -w
        Wait until the currently running wineserver terminates.
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/350695/execute-command-after-process-terminates-in-different-shell/454660), if it's not limited to wine.

That is, in order to wait for non-child processes, you have to check them periodically.