# execute command after process terminates in different shell

Tags: command-line, bash, shell

I am running a command that's processing some data in one shell window (let's say it has pid 200). Unfortunately I forgot to add the & to run it in the background.

I need to run some analysis script after pid 200 is finished. I thought I could just open up another shell window and do

```
wait 200; ./myanalysis.sh
```

But it complains to me

```
"-bash: wait: pid 200 is not a child of this shell"
```

With that in mind, is there a way I can execute my analysis script automatically after this process terminates?

Answer (score 4):

You can't "wait" for non-child processes, and you have to manually check it periodically. See for example [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058047/wait-for-any-process-to-finish).

Answer (score 2):

Can you use <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> and then do the following?

```
wait 200; ./myanalysis.sh&
fg %1
```

This will wait till pid `200` is finished, then run your analysis, and then will put itself in foreground.

Comment: You can if it's a child process of your current terminal...